# How do i condense this jQuery down so it's more efficient?

Tags: jquery, function

Below is some jQuery code the i wrote to make a simple animation. However I'm SO new to it i have no idea how to condense it down and get baffled by tutorials!

```
<!-- Login Form Div Animation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button-active').hide();
    if ($("#LoginButton").hasClass("inactive")) {
            $("#TopLoginForm").hide();
    } else {
            $("#TopLoginForm").show();
    }
    $("#LoginButton").click( function() {
        if ($("#LoginButton").hasClass("inactive")) {
            $("#LoginButton").animate({ 
                marginTop: "-40px"
                }, 500 );
            $("#button-inactive").animate({ 
                opacity: "0"
                }, 500 );
            $('#button-inactive').remove();
            $('#button-active').hide();
            $('#button-active').delay(30).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#LoginWelcome').delay(0).fadeOut(1000);
            $('#TopLoginForm').delay(800).fadeIn(1000);
            $("#LoginButton").addClass("button");
            $("#LoginButton.button").click( function() {
                document.forms["LoginForm"].submit();
            });
         }
    }); 
});
</script>
<!-- End Login Form Div Animation -->
```

The live code can be seen on www.trainingthemlive.co.uk/temp its at the top of the page

Comment: What do you mean by "condensed" and what do you mean "more efficient"?

Comment: You could also consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would have helped if your code was at least commented. As it is, everybody has to parse all of your code and try to imagine it against a DOM that has not been provided.

Comment: Do you want to improve execution performance? If execution performance is your target do you want to optimize based on this code or are you willing to reconstruct it entirely? Do you want to optimize for memory consumption or execution time? Do you want to minify the code to make transfers more efficient?

Comment: just an advise, use cursor: pointer in your buttons, imo using default text cursor in a button is ugly

Comment: @davidaam it may already be set in the css. there's no reason to do this in JS.

Comment: @MihaiStancu It's not set, look at his page, he posted it, I'm not saying to do it in the JS, if there's no reason to do it, it's ugly and bad practice too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's my own question and asked when I first signed up. It doesn't meet community standards and should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big thing you can do is avoid running the same query twice, if you know the results haven't changed. Chain or cache the results of your jQuery calls! Instead of:

```
$('#button-active').hide();
$('#button-active').delay(30).fadeIn(1000);
```

you can use the chainability of jQuery objects. In fact, you're already doing it in the second line--why not take the extra step?

```
$('#button-active').hide().delay(30).fadeIn(1000);
```

For readability:

```
$('#button-active')
    .hide()
    .delay(30)
    .fadeIn(1000);
```

But that's not the whole answer. Chaining is concise and great, if you need to do a bunch of stuff to one object or collection in sequence. But if you need to access one object, like `button-active`, at several different points during execution, you should store the query as a variable.

```
var $activeButton = $('#button-active'); // a common convention is to use the $ prefix on variables storing jQuery objects, but this is arguable & optional
```

All together, with a few other efficiency tricks:

```
;$(document).ready(function() {
    var   inactiveClass     = "inactive"
        , buttonClass       = "button"
        , fadeDuration      = 1000
        , animateDuration   = 500
        , shortDelay        = 30
        , longDelay         = 800

        , loginInactiveButtonAnimateTarget = {
            marginTop: -40
        }
        , inactiveButtonAnimateTarget = {
            opacity: 0
        }

        , loginButtonClickHandler = function() {
            document.forms["LoginForm"].submit() // not modifying this, but if this is the "TopLoginForm" then you could do this simpler
        }

        , $activeButton     = $('#button-active').hide() /* the .hide() method chains, so it returns the button-active object */
        , $loginButton      = $('#LoginButton')
        , $topLoginForm     = $('#TopLoginForm')
        , $loginWelcome     = $('#LoginWelcome')
        , $inactiveButton   = $('#button-inactive')

    if ($loginButton.hasClass(inactiveClass)) {
        $topLoginForm.hide()
    } else {
        $topLoginForm.show()
    }
    $loginButton.click(function() {
        if ($loginButton.hasClass(inactiveClass)) {
            $loginButton.animate(loginnactiveButtonAnimateTarget, animateDuration)
            $inactiveButton.animate(inactiveButtonAnimateTarget, animateDuration).remove()
            $activeButton.hide().delay(shortDelay).fadeIn(fadeDuration)
            $loginWelcome.delay(0).fadeOut(fadeDuration)
            $loginForm.delay(longDelay).fadeIn(fadeDuration)
            $loginButton.addClass(buttonClass).click(loginButtonClickHandler)
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One big thing regarding optimization in jQuery is knowing that the jQuery function `jQuery()` often aliased as `$()` is indeed a function.

That means that using `$('#some_id')` is actually calling a function which **looks for** the HTML element with the id #some_id. This is costly performance wise because **looking for** something in the DOM means traversing a tree and checking/ comparing the properties of the nodes.

You should fetch an HTML element from the DOM (with jQuery) and save the reference into a variable. And later on in the script you'll reference that HTML element using the same variable so as not to traverse the DOM again **looking for** the same element.

By using jQuery's `method chaining` approach (as suggested by @meloncholy) you would obtain the same benefits as defining a variable plus a more compact syntax. This is useful for manipulating an object you don't need a reference to later on, so you just stack-up all the manipulations you need done to it.

An example would be:

```
var some_object = $('#some_id');
some_object.hide();
if (some_object.hasClass('some_class')) {
    ...
```

I can't say that there will be a **noticeable** performance improvement to a script this size. If you had a few hundred lines of jQuery code all abusing the `jQuery()` function and a few hundred HTML elements in the tree and then you refactored the jQuery code as I indicated then you would have a speedup.

Comment: Just adding to this: as a lot of jQuery functions return the object you're manipulating, you can use chaining to do several things to the same element in succession. This saves time for the browser as @Mihai Stancu said, and also makes the code more compact, e.g. `$("#button-active").hide().delay(30).fadeIn(1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Best i get can do. You had a lot of repeating functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Start hidden
    $('#button-active').hide();
    $("#TopLoginForm").hide();

    // clicking "login"
    $("#LoginButton").click( function() {
    if ($("#LoginButton").hasClass("inactive")) {
        $("#LoginButton").animate({ 
            marginTop: "-40px"
            }, 500 );
        $('#LoginWelcome').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#button-active').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#TopLoginForm').fadeIn(1000);
        $("#LoginButton").addClass("button");
        $("#LoginButton.button").click( function() {
            document.forms["LoginForm"].submit();
        });
    }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on simplifying it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loginButton = $("#LoginButton");
    var topLoginForm = $("#TopLoginForm").toggle(!loginButton.hasClass("inactive"));
    loginButton.click( function() {
        var this$ = $(this);
        if (this$.hasClass("inactive")) {
            this$.animate({marginTop: "-40px"}, 500 );
            $("#button-inactive").animate({opacity: "0"}, 500, function() {$(this).remove();} );
            $('#button-active').hide().delay(30).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#LoginWelcome').fadeOut(1000);
            topLoginForm.delay(800).fadeIn(1000);
            loginButton.addClass("button").click( function() {
                document.forms["LoginForm"].submit();
            });
         }
    }); 
});
</script>
<!-- End Login Form Div Animation -->
```

Techniques used to simplify it:

- Chain multiple commands on the same jQuery object
- Use toggle(boolean) instead of if/else
- Save any jQuery object to a local variable that is used more than once
- Use completion function on animation so it isn't removed until after the animation finishes
- Remove `.delay(0)` since it doesn't do anything
- Use `this` in the event handler rather than rerunning the current selector

Comment: Hi guys.
Thanks so much for all your inputs! I must apologise, i am incredibly new to jQuery and this is intact the first thing i've attempted to make - so obviously lots of room for improvement! Also, first post on stack overflow, so again, apologies for any rules i may have broken etc. I've read all the comments and understood what you were saying and i will definitely look into it a lot more.

Seriously though, thanks again and i hope i can be a part of this community, just with better posts! haha

Andy